# Springboot javax.xml.ws.service Nullpointerexception while instantiating it

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, wsdl, webservice-client

I am developing a backend using springboot. I need to implement a soap client within my springboot application but I am facing an issue that I cannot understand why it is raised and how.

```
@WebServiceClient(name = "WSCryptDecrypt", targetNamespace = "example", wsdlLocation = "Example")
public class WSCryptDecrypt extends Service {

    private final static QName WSCRYPTDECRYPT_QNAME = new QName("Example", "WSCryptDecrypt");

    public WSCryptDecrypt(URL wsdlLocation) {
        super(wsdlLocation, WSCRYPTDECRYPT_QNAME);
    }
}
```

I instantiate this class like this:

```
WSCryptDecrypt wsCryptDecrypt = new WSCryptDecrypt(new URL("<WSDL-URL>"));
```

But I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:112) ~[jaxws-api-2.3.1.jar:na]
at com.mybackend.model.WSCryptDecrypt.<init>(WSCryptDecrypt.java:43) ~[classes/:na]
```

I don't get why and how this error is thrown. The url of the wsdl, that I pass as parameter, is correct for sure. I tried the code outside the springboot environmente and it works well. Springboot instead is complaining throwing this error.

**UPDATE:**

As @Laurens suggested I tried this approach:

Annotate WSCryptDecrypt class with **@Component** and then into WsCryptDecryptService class I do like that

```
@Autowired
WSCryptDecrypt wsCryptDecrypt;
```

In addition I annotated WsCryptDecryptService class with **@Service**

**UPDATE 2:**

javax.xml.ws.service class when instantiated it calls this.getClass().
Maybe this is the error, Spring did not create the Service object yet, so **this** is null. But I don't know how may I fix that.

**UPDATE 3:**
New fully updated code:

```
@Component
@WebServiceClient(name = "WSCryptDecrypt", targetNamespace = "example", wsdlLocation = "Example")
public class WSCryptDecrypt extends Service {

    private final static QName WSCRYPTDECRYPT_QNAME = new QName("Example", "WSCryptDecrypt");

    public WSCryptDecrypt(URL wsdlLocation) {
        // Here it throws the error
        super(wsdlLocation, WSCRYPTDECRYPT_QNAME);
    }
}
```

**Service class**

```
@Service
public class WsCryptDecryptService {

  //this is the soap service
  private WSCryptDecryptSoap wsCryptDecryptSoap;

  @Autowired
  WSCryptDecrypt wsCryptDecrypt;

   /**
   * Creates the service pointing to TEST Environment.
   * @throws MalformedURLException
   */
  public WsCryptDecryptService() {
    wsCryptDecryptSoap = wsCryptDecrypt.getWSCryptDecryptSoap();
  }
}
```

**UPDATE 4**

I thought that maybe it is a problem of dependency. Those are the dependency that I put in my pom for javax.xml.ws (They are more than needed just because I wanted to check that I load all the possible libraries)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jws</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.jws-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr181</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jws</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.springsource.javax.jws</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jws.jsr181-api</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr181-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxws-api-2.0</artifactId>
        <version>4.0-m1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: It's not your URL that's throwing the nullpointer. I'm pretty sure you can't initialize your service class with '= new Service', try injecting it with @Autowired.

Comment: I have already tried it but it doesn't work. It throws the same error.

Comment: Using the debugger seems that it is not able to find the class javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider through the FactoryFInder.find method (java.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder)

Comment: Try posting your full, updated code

Comment: I updated the code.

Comment: @Davide How did you solve this problem? I'm struck with the same issue.

Comment: @Ram I am sorry but I swapped to REST. I did not use soap at the end so I never solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

Don't instantiate your services, let Spring take care of this using @Autowired. I wouldn't recommend using a constructor as this is bad practise, just call the method when you need to request your WSCryptDecryptSoap

```
@Service
public class WsCryptDecryptService {

    @Autowired
    private WSCryptDecrypt wsCryptDecrypt;

    public WSCryptDecryptSoap getWSCryptDecryptSoap() {
        return wsCryptDecrypt.getWSCryptDecryptSoap();
    }
}
```

Comment: I know, I used the constructor just because I can see the error as soon as Spring start. If I let Spring to take care of It I need to run it and then to call the endpoint that use that service.
Anyway I updated my question and thank you very much for your help!